# IAsyncInfo Cancel method working for windows 8 BUT NOT for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Okay, I was reading Charles Petzold Programming Windows 6th edition but applying
it into windows phone 8.1 instead.
Currently I'm reading chapter 7 on Asynchronous.

I try to execute source code below which is working for Windows 8 app.
In this case, Dialog Box pop up for 5 second and automatically  dismissed.
But annoyingly on Windows Phone 8.1 , same source code compiles fine and running fine.
However dialog box pop up stay visible.

I believe there's some difference in way threading works between windows 8 and windows phone 8 app. 
NOTE: fyi, I tested this code in emulator

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncOp;

    async void Button_ClickCancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog("Choose a color", "How To Async #3");
        msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Red", null, Colors.Red));
        msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Blue Violet", null, Colors.BlueViolet));

        //Start a 5 second timer
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Start();

        asyncOp = msgdlg.ShowAsync();
        IUICommand command = null;

        try
        {
           command = await asyncOp;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("exception:[" + e.Message + "]");
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("##Before time.Stop()");
        //Stop the timer
        timer.Stop();

        //If the operation was cancelled, exit the method
        if (command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Get the color value and set the background brush
        Color clr = (Color)command.Id;
        ContentGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(clr);
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, object args)
    {
            asyncOp.Cancel();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more to do with a difference in the MessageDialog than in cancel not working.